# React js setAttribute("onClick", "????????") How to define path for the function

Tags: reactjs, onclick

```
  retrievePost() {
    alert();
  }

  componentDidMount() {   
        var newPost = document.createElement("a");
        var newTitle = document.createElement("div");

        newTitle.innerHTML = artist_val + " - " + title_val;
        newTitle.setAttribute("class", "music-title");

        newPost.setAttribute("onClick", "");
        newPost.append(newTitle);

        document.getElementsByClassName("scroll-menu")[0].append(newPost);
      });
    });
  }
```

What I want to do is giving onClick attribute to newPost, which is a tag, path to retrievePost with parameter. I have no idea how to. I ve done every way I can think of... like

retrievePost = (hi) => {} with (onClick, `${this.retrievePost(hi)}`) 
retrievePost(int hi) {} with (onClick, "retrievePost(hi)")

Help me out plzzz

Edit:

```
export class View extends React.Component {
  retrievePost(pa) {
    alert(pa);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Retrieving all data from database
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().orderByKey();
    ref.once("value").then(function (snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        var title_val = childSnapshot.val().Title;
        var artist_val = childSnapshot.val().Artist;

        var newPost = document.createElement("a");
        var newTitle = document.createElement("div");

        newTitle.innerHTML = artist_val + " - " + title_val;
        newTitle.setAttribute("class", "music-title");

        newPost.addEventListener("click", () => this.retrievePost("hi"));
        newPost.append(newTitle);

        document.getElementsByClassName("scroll-menu")[0].append(newPost);
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="view">
        <div className="view-container" data-aos="fade-in">
          <div className="view-content">
            <div className="view-content-header">
              <Link to="/">
                <img src={back} alt="back-icon" />
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="scroll-menu"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do not use `document.createElement` with react. Try to create a react component like this `let newComp = ({artist_val, title_val }) => <div onClick={retrievePost}>{artist_val} - {title_val}</div>` and call this component and pass it with your data.

Comment: it s saying 'retrievePost' is not defined  no-undef...

Comment: and the code is displaying as ({ artist_val, title_val }) => /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("div", { __self: this, __source: { fileName: _jsxFileName, lineNumber: 30, columnNumber: 11 } },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `addEventListener` instead of `setAttribute` for `click` event.

```js
...
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.retrievePost = this.retrievePost.bind(this);
}

retrievePost(param) {
  alert(param);
}

componentDidMount() {
  var newPost = document.createElement("a");
  var newTitle = document.createElement("div");

  newTitle.innerHTML = "some text";
  newTitle.setAttribute("class", "music-title");

  newPost.addEventListener("click", () => this.retrievePost("hi"));
  newPost.append(newTitle);

  document.getElementsByClassName("scroll-menu")[0].append(newPost);
}
```

[image: Edit vigorous-sky-9nxbc]

Comment: it s saying "Cannot read property 'retrievePost' of undefined"...

Comment: Weird, it's working on the codesanbox I shared above. Can you share me your code?

Comment: Yeha what the heck lol why is this not working for me!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I updated my answer, please try adding a `constructor` on your code like I did above.

Comment: Ohhh! Instead of using `ref.once("value").then(function (snapshot) {` you should use `ref.once("value").then((snapshot) => {`.

Comment: Still the same T.T

Comment: Also change this `snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {` to this `snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {`.

Comment: I have no idea how that change made it work but god I love you Thank you so much man

Comment: Haha! You're welcome, you should checkout what's `this` on JavaScript later. I think you don't need the `constructor` anymore.